# Modelling loaded data in java confusion

Tags: java, arraylist

So I am currently within a part of my assignment which focuses on "Modelling loaded data". So far, I have created a class that reads the contents of an external file using BufferedReader and FileReader. Next I have created a FlashCard class which has an ArrayList of flashcards. one set with a bunch of questions, the other with a bunch of answers. Before I put my issue across, I will show you what my program currently looks like so thatyou can better understand what I am stuck on.

**FlashCardReader class**

```
public class FlashCardReader 
{

BufferedReader reader = null;
String line;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void getLine()
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a file to read");
        try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\lee-pc\\Documents\\University\\Programming\\Lab9\\" + sc.next()));

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    ex.getMessage() + "File did not read correctly");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File was not found.");
    }        
    }
public void isReady()
{
  System.out.println("Please enter a file to read");
        try {

        reader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\lee-pc\\Documents\\University\\Programming\\Lab9\\" + sc.next()));

        try {

            if(reader.ready())
         {
            System.out.println("Is ready");
         }else 
                System.out.println("Not ready"); 

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                    ex.getMessage() + "File did not read correctly");
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File was not found.");
    }      
}
}
```

**FlashCard class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FlashCard 
{

         ArrayList<String> cardlist = new ArrayList<>();


FlashCard(String question, String answer)
{

}


public void getQuestion() 
{

cardlist.add("1Q - By what initials was Franklin Roosevelt better known?");
cardlist.add("2Q - Which number president was Franklin Roosevelt?");
cardlist.add("3Q - Which state was Franklin Roosevelt born in?");
cardlist.add("4Q - In which year did Roosevelt become Governor of New York?");
cardlist.add("5Q - What was the name of Franklin Roosevelt's wife?");
cardlist.add("6Q - How many children did Franklin Roosevelt have?");
cardlist.add("7Q - From which university did Franklin Roosevelt graduate with an A.B in history?");
cardlist.add("8Q - What was the first name of Franklin Roosevelt's 5th cousin, who was also President?");
cardlist.add("9Q - Which disease is believed to be the causes of Franklin Roosevelt's paralysis?");
cardlist.add("10Q - At what age did Franklin Roosevelt die?");

}

public void getAnswer()
{

 cardlist.add("1A - FDR");
 cardlist.add("2A - 32");
 cardlist.add("3A - New York");
 cardlist.add("4A - 1929");
 cardlist.add("5A - Elenor");
 cardlist.add("6A - 6");
 cardlist.add("7A - Hrrvard");
 cardlist.add("8A - Theodore");
 cardlist.add("9A - Polio");
 cardlist.add("10A - 63");

}

public ArrayList<String> getFlashCard()
{

return cardlist;

}
}
```

**Quiz**

```
 public class Quiz 
{

    FlashCard hold = new FlashCard("","");
public FlashCard flashCardHolder = hold;

}
```

This is what I have been instructed to do next:

- Create a Quiz class. This class will handle the interaction with the user. It should have a FlashCardReader and an instance variable that will hold the ArrayList of FlashCards.
- The constructor uses the getFlashCards() method, in the instance of FlashCardReader it has declared, to create and fill the ArrayList with FlashCards.

So I have created an instance variable in Quiz that creates a new FlashCard object. What's being asked next isn't clear to me so I have the following questions:

- What needs to happen for hold to contain the elements of the cardlist ArrayList?
- What is meant by "Create a Quiz class. This class will handle the interaction with the user. **It should have a FlashCardReader** and an instance variable that will hold the ArrayList of FlashCards."?
- How is the second bullet point implemented? How would the constructor use the getFlashCards() method to create and fill the ArrayList with FlashCards?

The instructions seems a little vague to me and I don't understand what needs to be done for this to be implemented so if anybody could help to that would be very much appreciated, thanks.